# $_SESSION variables not working

Tags: php

As a newcomer to PHP, I need to get $_SESSION variables working as part of a larger project. I am finding that the I cannot transfer data between .php files using $_SESSION variables. I Googled for similar problems and found this solved problem.[Same problem](http://x10hosting.com/forums/scripts-3rd-party-apps-programming/134814-php-session-not-working.html)

I reduced my code to the exact same as the solution to the problem, but it still exists. I have

**sesstest.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']="TEST SESSION TEXT";
header('location:sessreceive.php');
?>
```

**sessreceive.php**

```
<?php session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

I have cookies enabled and it is the same in Firefox and IE. The site I'm accessing is a Raspberry Pi on my home network. It is running Apache2 under a Linux version. The session part of my php.ini is

[image: Session section of php.ini]

Could anyone please suggest what might be wrong, as I get no output in sessreceive.php?

Comment: `var_dump(session_id());` on both pages right after `session_start();`. These id's should match up.

Comment: Had to temporarily comment out the 'header' line in sesstest, but having done that session_ids are the same in both

Comment: did you check the php log files? if something is missing it will be looged in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: @stefan - that must be it , not sure what to fix though:             [error] [client my IP address] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/home/pi/sessionsave/sess_nu0rvd7cqe9sgmchrhl94e5t75, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
[error] [client myIP] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/home/pi/sessionsave) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: does the directory /home/pi/sessionsave exist? if this was the case, do you have the rights to write data to this folder and/or is it owned by your www user?

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks - I did have /home/pi.. set as my save path but I removed it. HOWEVER I didn't restart apache. That solves the minimal example. I'll need to return to my full blown case tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `session.save_path` exists. Sometimes that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can try `var_dump($_SESSION);`, to see what exactly it contains.
2. Also, try `echo session_id();` in both cases to ensure you're picking up the same session in both cases.
3. Make sure Apache can write to the `session.save_path` (`/var/lib/php5`)

Comment: Hmm, In sesstest(if I comment out the header line):
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(17) "TEST SESSION TEXT" } 
In sessreceive when comment out removed:
array(0) { }